# How to find Action Script in a flash file (.fla file)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fla

I have to analyse data in a flash file. I have given with swf file , which i decompiled and produced .fla file which contains 35000 lines of code.

In that .fla file how to find user written code (i think so Action Script ). I am struggling with this.
Meanwhile i am preparing environment for flash editor with flashdevelope software.

Can somebody please suggest me how to find user written code in a flash file(.fla)

Comment: Press F9 then select layers on the left side panel

Answer (score 1):

You have to look on each and every keyframe which have an action symbol. I put an image to show how it will appear in flash file.

[image]

If your swf is targeted to AS3 then probably all the codes will decompiled in external ActionScript files. You will have to search in all the directories generated from your decompiler.

Edit

as @BadFeelingAboutThis suggests, there is another way by looking at the left panel within action panel.

[image]

Comment: Actually, in regards to the first part of your answer, FlashPro shows a code outline of all frame code and child code in the left hand pane of the actions panel (for the current scene).  This is much easier to navigate than clicking on individual key frames.  Try it out.  If you're so inclined, take a screenshot and update your answer.

Comment: Ah right, I always have that left panel hidden in my settings and rarely use the action panel. Thanks for the tip.